# mouse_event no funciona

Tags: c

Hola tengo un programa en  c que su funcion es mover el mouse y hacer doble click y abrirlo en mi caso un programa txt,al ejecutar el programa se mueve hacia el archivo pero no hace doble click ni click derecho ni nada, he buscado como solucionarlo y el codigo esta correcto, no da error al compilar etc

```
void main(){


int x,y;

// x = 670 y = 421
x = 666;
y = 402;

SetCursorPos(x,y);

//Click izquierdo
//mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0);

//Click derecho (abrir)
//mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,x,y,0,0);

//Doble click
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0);
```

`}`

Comment: Hola ruin_rain ! Viendo tu código no se ve nada incorrecto, a excepción de que deberías de llamar nuevamente a MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP para liberar el segundo click. ¿No realiza ningún click? ¿ha probado la funcion PostMessage en su lugar?

Comment: En teoria mouse_event deberia funcionar, el unico click que funciona es el click derecha i el izquierdo creo que tampoco asi que el error estaria ahi

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así a ver si te funciona:

```
/* Establecemos la posición del cursor */
SetCursorPos(x,y);
/* Simulamos evento DoubleClick */
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0,0,0,0);
delay(100);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Todavia sigue sin funcionar, en teoria al ejecutar el cmd deberia mostrar que ha funcionado pero se queda en negro y no da doble click al archivo txt

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre que compruebes que el dobleclick se produce. Si es así entonces el tema estaría en las coordenadas asignadas. SetCursorPos establece coordenadas relativas a la pantalla no a tu ventana. Usa las funciones ClientToScreen y ScreenToClient para convertir coordenadas.

Comment: El raton se mueve donde yo quiero es decir las coordenadas, estas las consigo meduante otro programa en c , ademas al ejecutar el puntero se mueve donde esta el archivo pero no me da ni click derecho ni doble click en cambio click izquierdo si

Comment: Se me ocurre que tal vez haya que situar un delay entre ambas simulaciones de click; es decir, una pequeña demora igual como ocurre cuando hacemos doble click. Prueba a insertar la linea delay(100);